# HackerRank | Roads and Libraries | Getting wrong answer in some test cases

Tags: c#

**My approach:**

According to the problem we have to *minimize the cost to repair the lib and the roads*. So what I did was `if the cost of repairing the lib is <= cost of repairing the roads` then I just simply `return (numberOfCities  * costOfRepairingLib)`. Otherwise I count the no of connected components and the no of roads to be repaired then I calculated the cost and return it.

And I'm unable to pass 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 and 10 test cases and the test cases are so huge that I can't even debug. Please see where I did the mistake.

[Link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/torque-and-development/problem)

---

The logic feels fine to me but its failing for large test cases even I change every data type to long. I'm really stuck on this.

```
class Solution {

    // Complete the roadsAndLibraries function below.
    static long roadsAndLibraries(long n, long c_lib, long c_road, long[][] cities) {
        if(c_lib <= c_road || c_road == 0)
            return c_lib * n;

        long[,] adjacentMatrix = new long[n, n];
        Stack<long> stack = new Stack<long>();
        Dictionary<long, bool> notVisited = new Dictionary<long, bool>();
        Dictionary<long, bool> visited = new Dictionary<long, bool>();

        for(long i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            notVisited[i] = false;
        }

        foreach(var city in cities){
            adjacentMatrix[city[0] - 1,city[1] -1] = 1;
            adjacentMatrix[city[1] - 1,city[0] - 1] = 1;
        }

        long noOfCycles = 0;
        long noOfRoads = 0;

        while(notVisited.Count > 0){
            stack.Push(notVisited.ElementAt(0).Key);
            visited.Add(stack.Peek(), true);
            notVisited.Remove(notVisited.ElementAt(0).Key);
            noOfCycles++;
            while(stack.Count > 0){
                long top = stack.Pop();
                for(long i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    if(adjacentMatrix[top - 1, i] == 1 && !visited.ContainsKey(i + 1)){
                        visited.Add(i + 1, true);
                        noOfRoads++;
                        stack.Push(i + 1);
                        notVisited.Remove(i + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (noOfCycles * c_lib) + (noOfRoads * c_road);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        long q = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

        for (long qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++) {
            string[] nmC_libC_road = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            long n = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[0]);

            long m = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[1]);

            long c_lib = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[2]);

            long c_road = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[3]);

            long[][] cities = new long[m][];

            for (long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                cities[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), citiesTemp => Convert.ToInt64(citiesTemp));
            }

            long result = roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities);

            textWriter.WriteLine(result);
        }

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation of what you want to achieve **into the question** including a [mcve]. We're not here to do your home work for you

Comment: Not only what Liam mentioned, but please add specific details about the errors you are getting in the test case, for now, we would be stuck at uploading your implementation, and then having the test fail. Now I am assuming that the Main part is not your code, but only the `roadsAndLibraries` method?

Comment: I'm new here. Shall I explain the code or the problem statement?

Comment: @Liam I have added my approach. Can you please let me know if I should add something else?

Comment: @Icepickle I have added my approach. Can you please let me know if I should add something else?

Comment: I wonder, did you check with of the cities are in a connected block as well? As far as I understood the problem, if they are, there is no need to (re)build  any roads once a mainroad was established. Why do your test fail, do they timeout, or give the wrong output?

Comment: @SubhamRaj I'd advise you read the [help]. Specifically the [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Icepickle There should be at least one library for each city in a connected component. And my code doesn't timeout it just gives wrong output.

Comment: @Icepickle Here vertices are cities and edges are roads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So I found out what was going wrong with my code**

My logic was totally correct the thing where I wasn't able to guess what was happening is that *HACKERRANK* handles *OutOfMemoryException* badly, they show wrong answer instead of showing that exception. So I changed my code to improve the time & space complexity .

So what I did is:

1. I removed the two *dictionaries* (visited and notVisited) and added a visited *array* instead as the array lookup will be quicker because a dictionary lookup is two operations: calculate the hash of the key to get an index and retrieve the value from an internal array at that index.
2. Used *adjacency list* instead of *adjacency matrix*.

**CODE:**

```
class Solution {

    // Complete the roadsAndLibraries function below.
    static long roadsAndLibraries(long n, long c_lib, long c_road, long[][] cities) {
        if(c_lib <= c_road || cities.Length == 0)
            return c_lib * n;

        long[,] adjacentMatrix = new long[n + 1, n + 1];
        Stack<long> stack = new Stack<long>();
        bool[] visited = new bool[n + 1];

        foreach(var city in cities){
            adjacentMatrix[city[0], city[1]] = 1;
            adjacentMatrix[city[1], city[0]] = 1;
        }

        // for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
        //     for(int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++){
        //         Console.Write(adjacentMatrix[i,j]+" ");
        //     }
        //     Console.WriteLine();
        // }

        long noOfComponents = 0;
        long noOfEdges = 0;

        for(long i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            if(visited[i]){
                continue;
            }
            stack.Push(i);
            visited[i] = true;
            noOfComponents++;
            while(stack.Count > 0){
                long top = stack.Pop();
                for(long j = 0; j <= n; j++){
                    if(!visited[j] && adjacentMatrix[top,j] == 1){
                        stack.Push(j);
                        visited[j] = true;
                        noOfEdges++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Console.WriteLine(noOfCycles+" "+noOfRoads);

        return noOfComponents * c_lib + noOfEdges * c_road;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        long q = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

        for (long qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++) {
            string[] nmC_libC_road = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            long n = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[0]);

            long m = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[1]);

            long c_lib = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[2]);

            long c_road = Convert.ToInt64(nmC_libC_road[3]);

            long[][] cities = new long[m][];

            for (long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                cities[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), citiesTemp => Convert.ToInt64(citiesTemp));
            }

            long result = roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities);

            textWriter.WriteLine(result);
        }

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded the following to solve the problem, but there are still 6 out of 13 tests failed. How to pass all tests?

```
   using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Runtime.Serialization;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   using System.Text;
   using System;

 class Result
 {

/*
 * Complete the 'roadsAndLibraries' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER n
 *  2. INTEGER c_lib
 *  3. INTEGER c_road
 *  4. 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY cities
 */
static Dictionary<int, List<int>> adj;
static long costRd;
static bool[] visited;
private static long nconnected;
public static long roadsAndLibraries(int n, int c_lib, int c_road, List<List<int>> cities)
{
    if(c_lib <= c_road ) return n*c_lib;
    costRd = 0;
    nconnected = 0;
    visited= new bool[n +1];

    adj = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();  
    for (int i =0; i< cities.Count(); i++) {
        int u = cities[i][0];
        int v = cities[i][1];
        if (!adj.ContainsKey(u)) {
            var list = new List<int> ();
            adj[u] = list;
        }         
        adj[u].Add(v);
        if (!adj.ContainsKey(v)) {
            var list = new List<int> ();
            adj[v] = list;
        }
        adj[v].Add(u);                
    } 
    for(int i =0; i< n; i++) {
        if(!visited[i+1]) {   
          nconnected++;
          DFS( i+ 1);            
        }
    }
    return costRd *c_road + nconnected * c_lib;
}
private static void DFS(int node)
{
  visited[node] =true;
  if (!adj.ContainsKey(node)) return;
  foreach( var num in adj[node]) {
    if(!visited[num]){
      costRd++;
      DFS(num);            
    }
  }   
  }
 }

 class Solution
 {
   public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     TextWriter textWriter = new 
     StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

     int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

    for (int qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++)
    {
        string[] firstMultipleInput = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ');

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(firstMultipleInput[0]);

        int m = Convert.ToInt32(firstMultipleInput[1]);

        int c_lib = Convert.ToInt32(firstMultipleInput[2]);

        int c_road = Convert.ToInt32(firstMultipleInput[3]);

        List<List<int>> cities = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            cities.Add(Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(citiesTemp => Convert.ToInt32(citiesTemp)).ToList());
        }

        long result = Result.roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);
    }

    textWriter.Flush();
    textWriter.Close();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please see answer to this post --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57638843/10353588